# gcp redis auth by custom username and password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis

Recently, I plan to migrate my `Alibaba Cloud Redis` to `Google Cloud Platform(gcp) Redis`. My web project is now using the user name and password for Alibaba Cloud Redis auth. I know that gcp Redis can enable auth and obtain a random password after creating a Redis instance, but I cannot customize the auth and find a way to set a custom user name for auth.

I just want to replace the Redis host in my web project configuration file, and don't need to change any code in my project. If GCP does not support username for auth, it means I have to change some code to be compatible with different Redis, which may be bring me some potential bugs.

Comment: Did you try something? maybe to simply set up your Memorystore and then to add a user as you do usually with Redis?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Sure, I've searched the official doc of memorystore and tried to find the way to add a user in memorystore, but stiil got nothing.

Comment: How does it work today? Do you have a login/password?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere There hasn't been much progress yet.

Comment: No, your Redis!! Today, how does it authenticate the client?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Verify through username and auth.

Comment: You should be able to do the same with Memorystore. Keep in mind that is not a Google Product, it's only a redis, but fully managed by Google. Same feature, same tools, only the installation, update, patching, HA (...) managed by Google and not by you. So the same feature are avaible!